# using "shuf" to randomly output lines in a range

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to randomly generate password from a file.I need to read/output 3-5 line from that file so I can use those lines to generate password. Find out that shuf is perfect to finish the task. It has an option -n so the command output at most #'s lines

for example

```
shuf -n 5 filename
```

randomly outputs 5 line.

Anyone knows how to output not just 5 but 3 to 5 line by using shuf? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to generate a random numbers from 0 to 2 and add 3:

```
shuf -n $(($RANDOM % 3 + 3)) filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pwgen`. Like this:

```
pwgen -S 12 1
```

This will generate a 12 column "secure" password. There are many other options to `pwgen`. Check the man page.

Comment: does this require a extra package? My konsloe gives me no manual entry for pwgen

Comment: yeah, you would need to install `pwgen`. On Debian/Ubuntu : `sudo apt-get install pwgen` on Centos/RedHatEL/Fedora `sudo yum install pwgen` (other distros will work too of course, however I don't know those commands)

Comment: i would like to not use extra package.. but thanks for helping!!

Comment: Why will you reinvent the wheel? I bet your solution isn't as half as secure as `pwgen`. It has been evaluated over the years.

Comment: it is a school homework, I don't think my professor would like me to use something requires extra package...